# AWS EB Node.JS Log to CloudWatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

is there any possible solution to stream Node.JS log of application running on Elastic Beanstalk to Amazon CloudWatch?

I did saw **cwl-webrequest-metrics.config** file but with no information about it's format I can not format it to stream Node.JS log (only) to CloudWatch.

That you in advance for your comments!

Comment: can you please elaborate more about stream , you want like we do "tail -f /logs" ?

Comment: I just would love /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log to be automatically streamed from EB to CloudWatch and thats it.

Answer (score 4):

Question's a little old, but for those of you coming from Google, here's a working .ebextension config for Node.JS log streaming into cloudwatch:

```
# Store Node.JS Application Logs in Cloudwatch
Mappings:
  CWLogs:
    NodeJSLogGroup:
      LogFile: "/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log"
      TimestampFormat: "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z"

Outputs:
  NodeJSCWLogGroup:
    Description: "Node.JS Application Logs"
    Value: { "Ref" : "AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0NodeJSLogGroup"}


Resources :
  AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0NodeJSLogGroup:    ## Must have prefix:  AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    DependsOn: AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata
    DeletionPolicy: Retain     ## this is required
    Properties:
      LogGroupName:
        "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
          Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
          OptionName: NodeJSCWLogGroup
          DefaultValue: {"Fn::Join":["-", [{ "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "nodejs"]]}
      RetentionInDays: 14


  ## Register the files/log groups for monitoring
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":
        CWLogsAgentConfigSetup:
          files:
            ## any .conf file put into /tmp/cwlogs/conf.d will be added to the cwlogs config (see cwl-agent.config)
            "/tmp/cwlogs/conf.d/nodejs.conf":
              content : |
                [nodjs-log]
                file = `{"Fn::FindInMap":["CWLogs", "NodeJSLogGroup", "LogFile"]}`
                log_group_name = `{ "Ref" : "AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0NodeJSLogGroup" }`
                log_stream_name = {instance_id}
                datetime_format = `{"Fn::FindInMap":["CWLogs", "NodeJSLogGroup", "TimestampFormat"]}`
              mode  : "000400"
              owner : root
              group : root
```

Looks like http://serebrov.github.io/html/2015-05-20-cloudwatch-setup.html might be a good reference as well.

Comment: FYI on Linux 2, AWS uses `/var/log/web.stdout.log` instead of `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`